# Draw multiple polygon inside rectangle based on line intersection point

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I have created below SVG using [svg.js 2.7](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/)

Now I want to draw all possible polygons made based on lines intersection with other line and outer rectangle.

I have got all intersection points for lines and lines intersection with the outer rectangle using svg.js plugin [svg-intersections-js](https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/plugins/svg-intersections-js/)

My requirement is, I want to display a hover effect for every possible polygon.

**Edit 1:** Line position and alignment are dynamic.

Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Most likely, the answer to your question is `yes`. If you also want to know how, you have better chances by providing the code of the svg and your attempt at a solution. You can use the snippet tool for that.

Comment: @vqf, I have svg with an id for lines and outer rectangle, Can you let me know how can I identify the polygons forming by lines. Is there any javascript library available?

Comment: What's stops you from just creating all the polygon elements and adding a css hover?

Comment: @Fuzzyma, these lines are not static, it is draggable and the user can also change its alignment, so need to calculate all dynamically.

Comment: Is it possible to draw multiple polygons based on dynamic intersection points?